# Order of events with chained keyBy calls on same key

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

From [this link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/concepts/programming-model.html#parallel-dataflows) I understand that the order of events that come from some inDataStream is preserved per key in the following resulting outDataStream:

```
outDataStream = inDataStream.keyBy(...)
    .timeWindow(...)
    .reduce(...)
```

So, for example, if we have the following events entered from inDataStream (we do keyBy on the keys):

(1, key1), (2, key1), (3, key2), (4, key1), (5, key2)

Then the outDataStream will preserve the same order for the events of key1 and the events of key2. So such result of outDataStream could NEVER happen:

(2, key1), (1, key1), (3, key2), (4, key1), (5, key2)

(Because 1 and 2 switched).

So far, am I correct?
Then if we chain another keyBy/process we again result with same order, right? Because we simply apply again the same guarantee.. Since order of same keys is critical for us, then to make sure we are on the same page I made simplified version of what we have:

```
// incoming events. family is used for keyBy grouping.
case class Event(id: Int, family: String, value: Double)
// the aggregation of events
case class Aggregation(latsetId: Int, family: String, total: Double)

// simply adding events into total aggregation
object AggFunc extends AggregateFunction[Event, Aggregation, Aggregation] {
override def add(e: Event, acc: Aggregation) = Aggregation(e.id, e.family, e.value + acc.total)
override def createAccumulator() = Aggregation(-1, null, 0.0)
override def getResult(acc: Aggregation) = acc
}

object ProcessFunc extends ProcessFunction[Aggregation, String] {
override def processElement(agg: Aggregation, ctx: ProcessFunction[Aggregation, String]#Context, out: Collector[String]) =
  out.collect(s"Received aggregation combined with event ${agg.latsetId}. New total=${agg.total}")
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)
// incoming events from a source have 2 families: "A", and "B"
env.fromElements(Event(1, "A", 6.0), Event(2, "B", 4.0), Event(3, "A", -2.0), Event(4, "B", 3.0),
    Event(5, "A", 8.0), Event(6, "B", 1.0), Event(7, "A", -10.0))
  .keyBy(_.family)
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(1))
  .trigger(CountTrigger.of(1)) // FIRE any incoming event for immediate aggregation and ProcessFunc application
  .aggregate(AggFunc)
  .keyBy(_.family)
  .process(ProcessFunc)
  .print()
}
```

So for such events coming into the first keyBy in that order - for any operator parallelism and cluster deployment, we are guaranteed that the Sink (here print()) will always receive the following aggregations of family "A" and in that order (but possibly mixed with aggregations of family "B"):

```
"Received aggregation combined with event 1. New total=6.0"
"Received aggregation combined with event 3. New total=4.0"
"Received aggregation combined with event 5. New total=12.0"
"Received aggregation combined with event 7. New total=2.0"
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink only guarantees order within a parallel partition, i.e., it does not communicate across partitions and hold back data to guarantee order.

This means, that if you have the following operators:

```
map(Mapper1).keyBy(0).map(Mapper2)
```

and run this with parallelism of 2, i.e.,

```
Mapper1(1) -\-/- Mapper2(1)
             X
Mapper1(2) -/-\- Mapper2(2)
```

Then all records with the same key from `Mapper1(1)` will arrive in order at either `Mapper2(1)` or `Mapper2(2)` depending on the key. Of course the same is true for all records with the same key from `Mapper1(2)`.

So, as soon as records with the same key are distributed across multiple partitions (here `Mapper1(1)` and `Mapper1(2)`) there are no ordering guarantees for records of different partitions but only for those that are in the same partition.

If order is important, you can either reduce the parallelism to 1 or implement your operators with event-time semantics and leverage watermarks to reason about the out-of-orderness of records.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. I would like to make sure that subsequent keyBy calls over the same key field will maintain order over that key:    

map(Mapper1).keyBy(0).map(Mapper2).keyBy(0).map(Mapper3).addSink(Sink)    

So all elements with key k1 will arrive into the same Mapper3 subtask, and then into the only one sink subtask, in the same order they arrived into the Mapper2 subtask. The key function and it's input from elements are the same all the way.

Comment: That is correct given that the sink and `Mapper3` have the same parallelism (and `Mapper2` doesn't change the key field).

Comment: Fabian, the order of elements of the **same key** will will be preserved between outgoing stream of Mapper3 and incoming stream of sink - for a sink with **parallelism==1** and Mapper3 with **any** parallelism. Is it correct? I mean, all the elements of key "k1" get into one Mapper3 subtask with some order (so it doesn't matter which parallelism Mapper3 has), and they will be handled and leave that Mapper3 subtask again in that order, then arriving into that one sink subtask and handled by it - again, in that same order. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Obviously, the sink will handle records with all keys but records with the same key won't be shuffled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can safely assume either that the absolute order of stream elements will be maintained with parallelism > 1.

Additionally I do not think that order at all can be assumed once it hits the aggregation operator. The output of the aggregation operator is based on internal window timers and the keys should not be assumed to be kept in any particular order.

If you require ordering then your best bet I think is to sort the data after it comes out into what you need.